# Error appears while searching joke from relational database

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I am using ***Server version 10.1.21-MariaDB and mysql*** for performing data operation. I am creating mini search tool for searching jokes.The overview of how i am performing it is shown in image. Everything works fine but when i try to execute sql statement,it shows syntax error. I tried to dig inside it but as i am quite new to this stuff,i lost here and there digging the exact way of using syntax. The error is shown in bold letter and code is provided below where error occurs.I think error must be inside the try block,please help me to sort this out.

[image]

```
//query logic
$select = 'SELECT id,joketext ';
$from   = 'FROM joke_info';
$where  = 'WHERE TRUE';

$placeholders = array();

if(isset($_GET['author']) != ''){
  $where .= " AND authorid = :authorid";
  $placeholders[':authorid'] = $_GET['author'];
}
if(isset($_GET['category']) != ''){

  $from .= ' INNER JOIN jokecategory ON id = jokeid';
  $where .= " AND categoryid = :categoryid";
  $placeholders[':categoryid'] = $_GET['category'];
}
if ($_GET['text'] != '') 
{
  $where .= " AND joketext LIKE :joketext";
  $placeholders[':joketext'] = '%' . $_GET['text'] . '%';
}

print_r($placeholders);
try
{
  $sql = $select . $from . $where;
  $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $s->execute($placeholders);
}catch (PDOException $e)
{
  $error = 'Error fetching jokes. ';
  echo $error.$e->getMessage();
  exit();
}
```

***Error Says this:***
**Array ( [:authorid] => 6 [:categoryid] => 10 [:joketext] => %been working% ) Error fetching jokes. SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'TRUE AND authorid = '6' AND categoryid = '10' AND joketext LIKE '%been working%'' at line 1**

Comment: print the generatet query

Comment: To be fair, i dnt know exactly how to do it. Plz help me out. Error is inside try block thats what i can say for sure.

Comment: I think you are missing a condition for the where clause. you should have something allong the lines of 'WHERE someValue = True and ....

Comment: @Jens i doesn't work out.i changed it

Comment: @Brian I am referring php_mysql_novice_to_ninja, it says simply $where ='WHERE TRUE' nothing more than this.

Comment: @Jens yup, it still shows same error message.

Comment: @Jens, Nope,same error message still.

Comment: @jens, thanks a lot for co-ordination. As per comment below, i must insert spaces while appending those statement. It resolved out.

Comment: But if you have changed `'WHERE TRUE` to `WHERE 1=1` can the error message be ` near 'TRUE AND`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your generated query after `$sql = $select . $from . $where;` will be something like `SELECT id,joketext FROM joke_info WHERE TRUE`
So there is no space between joke_info and Where clause
It should be `$from = ' FROM joke_info' and $where = ' WHERE TRUE ';` instead of `$from = 'FROM joke_info' and '$where ='WHERE TRUE';`

Answer (score 1):

Ther is no space between $from and $where variables. Currently they are concatenating to: 'FROM joke_infoWHERE TRUE'. Try giving a space in the $from variable.